# What regex can capture 2 exact 'words' in a phrase?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to capture words constant in a string. That constant is:

1. a word
2. followed by **one** separator (whitespace, dot, dash or underscore)
3. another word
4. and then a separator (see #2) or the end of the line or string.

For the sake example let's say I'm looking for "Bob 1", in the following strings:

```
Hello, I'm Bob 1 --> Should capture Bob 1
Hello, I'm Bob 11 --> Should capture nothing (Bob 1 is not at the end or followed by a separator)
Hey, it's Bob-1 over there --> Should capture Bob-1
Hey, it's Bob - 1 over there --> Should capture nothing (Bob should be followed only by one separator not 3 like here)
Bob.1 --> Should capture Bob.1
Bob_1 rules! --> Should capture Bob_1
```

I have a regex that mostly works:

```
/Bob[\s._-]1[\s._-]/ig
```

In the second list I don't know how to add the end of the string in the possible characters... Which ends in only the last line in the live demo below that should be a match and that isn't captured.

See the [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/qMdzEs/5).

I use pcre (in PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using PHP, but the following matches for me:

```
\bBob[\s.\-_]1\b
```

It is making use of `\b` which matches against a word boundary. I found that I had to escape the dash inside the square brackets, which isn't something you are doing but that may be a difference between the regex engines we are using.

Comment: Just to add, that you need to check what comes before "Bob" because "Bob" might be part of a string hence why I included a \b at the start.

Comment: I don't need do escape it in my example because it's the last character of the list. If it's not the engine thinks it's a character range and you need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

This works

https://regex101.com/r/ezikuP/2

`(?<!\S)Bob[\s._-]1(?![^\s._-])`

[Formatted](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?<! \S )               # Whitespace boundary
 Bob                     # Word 1
 [\s._-]                 # Special seperator
 1                       # Word 2
 (?! [^\s._-] )          # Special seperator boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

> Which ends in only the last line in the live demo below that should be a match and that isn't captured.

For that you need a positive lookahead.

**Regex:** `Bob[\s._-]1(?=[\s._-])`

- `(?=[\s._-])` will only look for give character class and won't match/capture it.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qMdzEs/2)**

Answer (score 0):

> In the second list I don't know how to add the end of the string in the possible characters.

You can use this regex with anchor `$` to assert end of string:

```
/\bBob[\s._-]1(?:[\s._-]|$)/m
```

OR if you don't want to match next character after 2nd word then use a lookahead:

```
/\bBob[\s._-]1(?=[\s._-]|$)/m
```

`([\s._-]|$)` will assert presence of given (one of whitespace, DOT, Underscore, Hyphen) characters or end of line `$`.

It is safer to add `\b` before `Bob` to match exact word `Bob` and avoid matching `HelloBob`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qMdzEs/3)